# Is there a way to use get_sidebar() when no widgets are activated?

Tags: widgets, sidebar, theme-twenty-sixteen

WP version 4.4.2, I have a customized `sidebar.php` and no widgets activated, which automatically prohibits `get_sidebar()` function to load contents of `sidebar.php`. Is there a way to forcefully load `sidebar.php` file?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, default `twentysixteen` theme had additional function to add body class:

```
if ( ! is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) {
    $classes[] = 'no-sidebar';
}
```

So that was the reason for sidebar not to show up.